# One hop flight challenge

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, data-structures

I have a list of tuples of flights from sources to destinations. Eg: [(2,3),(1,2),(3,1),(1,3),(3,2),(2,4),(4,1)]

I want to return a list of tuples of all flights that have ONE connecting flight between them. For example, the answer to the above list would be [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 2), (4, 3)]

I'm a beginner in python and have been trying to solve it for quite some time now and have come up with the following code.
Is my logic wrong? I feel I can there's a shorter way to this using list comprehensions or something but I'm not too sure. Do give me suggestions on how to go about this.

```
def one_hop(l):
    source = [i[0] for i in l]
    dest = [j[1] for j in l]
    (i, j, one) = (0, 0, [])
    for i in source:
        for j in dest:
            if source.index(i) != dest.index(j) and j in dest and i != j:
                index1 = dest.index(j)
                if source[index1] in dest and source[index1] != j and dest.index(source[index1]) != source.index(i) and i == source[dest.index(source[index1])]:
                    one.append((i,j))
    return one
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you asked for comprehension (although this is inefficient):

```
sorted(set((u[0],v[1]) for u in l for v in l if u[1]==v[0] and u[0]!=v[1]))
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Why would it be inefficient though?

Comment: it has quadratic complexity i. e. for every element it loops through every element. think of 10000 airports with a max of 10000*9999=10e8 flights. say there are 10^6 flights this results in 10^12 one-stop-checks. i assume there are more efficient algorithms by e. g. building graphs.